# Htaccess redirect after changing Language URL format

Tags: htaccess

After have changed the URL language format from

```
http://my-site.com/name-of-page/?lang=en
http://my-site.com/name-of-page/?lang=ru
```

to

```
http://my-site.com/en/name-of-page/
http://my-site.com/ru/name-of-page/
```

I'd like to redirect the former URL versions to the actual ones.

I found this code snippet online and apparently it partially solves my problem.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=en
# exclude all requests starting with /wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /en/$1? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

However, it is designed for `lang=en` only!

How could I also include `lang=ru` in it so that it will redirect both `lang=en` and `lang=ru`?

Thank you in advance for any valuable hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to catch either `lang=en` or `lang=ru` you can change those directives like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=(en|ru)
# exclude all requests starting with /wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1? [L,R=302]
```

The `(en|ru)` part matches either `en` or `ru` and the surrounding parentheses make this a *capturing group* that can be referenced later.

The `%1` (note the `%`, not `$`) in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* is a backreference to the captured group mentioned above. So, `%1` holds either `en` or `ru`.

The trailing `.*$` on the end of `!^/wp-admin/.*$` is superfluous. As is the `^` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `(.*)` - since regex is greedy by default.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect and only change to 301 (permanent) when you are sure this is working OK - to avoid caching issues.

Comment: If you'd like to test even earlier in the process than @MrWhite suggested, you can try here first https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ once you get what you want there, try on your production environment with 302s and finally switch to 301 when you're satisfied.

Comment: @zfors Unfortunately, the _mwl tool_ you link to is buggy and does not work with the solution - as written - in my answer. To make it work in the tool, you need to reverse the two conditions - but that is not necessary on a real server (since negated conditions are not considered a successful "match" and therefore do not capture any backreferences).